# Which version of SQL Server 2016 does TFS 2018 require?

Tags: sql-server, tfs

We're running TFS 2015. I'd like to upgrade us to TFS 2018. Searching on the 'net I've learned that TFS 2018 requires SQL Server 2016. What I don't know is if it requires SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition or SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Edition. Which is it?

Comment: Did you refer to the system requirements documentation? It explicitly states what versions are supported.

Comment: No, I do not know where that is.

Comment: Azure DevOps Server supports Express, Standard, and Enterprise SQL Server editions. The Express edition is recommended only for evaluation purposes, personal use, or for very small teams. We recommend the SQL Server Standard or Enterprise versions for all other scenarios. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops

Comment: @Rod Did you try Googling "tfs system requirements" and looking at the results that are returned?

Comment: Thank you, Piotr. Daniel, no I hadn't thought to search for that term, sorry. I tried a different search term which brought me to Brian Harry's blog post, which didn't mention anything as to which version of SQL Server 2016, TFS 2018 requires. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/team-foundation-server-2018-and-sql-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can use both.
It will detect if you have Enterprise and use some Enterprise features if you have it.

Few more details at: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2712111/disabling-sql-server-data-compression-in-tfs-databases

Comment: And since Data Compression is available on Standard edition since 2016 SP1, not sure if it matter anymore.

Comment: Thank you, Piotr.